# Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: c, linux, sockets, solaris, lib

I was coding a simple socket agent program in LINUX system(Ubuntu 16.04 server).

When I run this program in Solaris, It gets the following error:

```
Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

This list is what I included.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

Why is this happening? Please let me know.....

Comment: You mean run without recompiling? You can't just copy any linux binary and expect it work on another OS

Comment: Does It need recompile? Are not they the same ELF file?

Comment: I would suggest that you recompile. There's apparently some emulation layers for linux binaries on solaris, but they seem to have their limitiations. If you have the source just compile it for solaris instead. It's a different OS. There's more to a system environment than its binary containerformat and instruction set.

Comment: Solaris & Linux use the same ELF format, but different libraries & system calls, so a recompile is required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solaris is not Linux.  The system libraries will most likely be in different locations.    You will need to recompile your program on Solaris.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer has been a great help to me.